# Critical Update: Trust Percent Values in Flow sObject Variables Again - 2

Tags: formula-field, spring16, critical-update, percent

Is this update is only for Flows (Like visual flows) and it does not have any impact on regular percentage field or formula field or formula field using percentage data?

Note: I earlier posted **[THIS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139088/critical-update-trust-percent-values-in-flow-sobject-variables-again)** where I was not able to reproduce the example mentioned in the update. But now when I try the same with flows I see the discrepancy as in the example.

Comment: Is this question really any different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for flows, which were causing percentage fields to scale down incorrectly between variables. Normal formulas work as they always have, are not broken, and will not be affected by the update.